# Distinguishing uniformly random bit string $x$ from added bitstring $a \wedge b$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose you are given a bit string $x \in \{0,1\}^n$. How would you distinguish whether this bit string was uniformly random or is generated by taking 2 uniformly random bit strings and bitwise anding them like so $a,b \in \{0,1\}, x=a\wedge b$.

In particular the algorithm you come up with that distinguishes the input bitstring $A$ has to be such that

$$P_{x \in \{0,1\}} [A(x)=1] < 2^{-n/100}, P_{x,x' \in \{0,1\}} [A(x \wedge x') =1] > 1-2^{-n/100}$$

We are also given Chernoff bound in the form:

If $X_1,...,X_n \in {0,1}$ are uniformly random vars with $P(X_i=1)=p,$ then for any $\epsilon>0$

$$P[X_1 +.. + X_n \geq (p+\epsilon)n] \leq 2^{-\epsilon^2 n}, P[X_1 +.. + X_n \leq (p-\epsilon)n] \leq 2^{-\epsilon^2 n}$$

So i know that if we have a uniform bit string then the expected number of 1s is $n/2$ whereas for an anded bit string its $n/4.$ And the Chernoff bound is a statement about the probability of the number of 1s being greater than expected value and lower than expected. So that leads me to $A$ being something like count the number of 1s and then if its greater than a threshold output 1 or 0. But im unsure of how to find this threshold or if this is even the right idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Notice that when sampling a random bit string uniformly, each element will be $1$ with probability $1/2$. On the other hand, when sampling $2$ bit strings uniformly and then anding them, the resulting bit string will have each element equal to $1$ with probability $1/4$. Notice how the entries remain independent in the second construction. To make the Chernoff bounds work, we will design a test that outputs $1$ when $\{x_1+\dots+x_n < \epsilon n\}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ that is convenient.

I will present the thought process of choosing an appropriate $\epsilon$. When our bit string $\mathbf{x} \in \{0,1\}^n$ is truly uniform then we know that
$$P(X_1 + \dots + X_n \leq (0.5-\epsilon')n)\leq 2^{-\epsilon' ^2 n}$$
while when $\mathbf{x}$ is generated by the anding method,
$$P(X_1+\dots + X_n \geq (0.25 + \epsilon')n) \leq 2^{-\epsilon' ^2 n}$$
for $\epsilon' > 0$. Here we denote with capital $X_i$'s the random variables corresponding to the string indices.

We select $\epsilon'$ such that the quantities $0.5-\epsilon'$ and $0.25+\epsilon'$ are equal, so $\epsilon'=0.125$. Now take $\epsilon=0.5-\epsilon'=0.375$.

Summarizing, we created a test $A: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ such that $A(\mathbf{x})= 1 \Longleftrightarrow x_1+\dots+x_n<0.375n$.
The first of the above inequalities gives an upper bound on the probability of a false positive (i.e $\mathbf{x}$ is truly uniform and $A(\mathbf{x})=1$). The second one bounds the probability of a false negative (i.e $\mathbf{x}$ is generated by anding and $A(\mathbf{x})=0$). The required bounds easily follow!